# Stripe Checkout iOS integration with Storyboards in Swift 3

Tags: ios, storyboard, swift3, segue, stripe-payments

I am following the [Stripe Standard](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/tree/master/Example/Stripe%20iOS%20Example%20(Simple)) iOS integration "Example/Simple" in Swift 3

However, I am using storyboards and have integrated the code to work well so far. But I am having issues instantiating the [STPPaymentMethodsViewController](https://stripe.github.io/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPPaymentMethodsViewController.html) on the navigation stack when calling this code

From CheckoutRowView:

```
func didTap() {
    self.onTap()
}
```

followed by

```
var onTap: () -> () = {}
```

To CheckoutViewController:

```
var paymentContext = STPPaymentContext()

let paymentRow: CheckoutRowView

viewDidLoad() {
self.paymentRow.onTap = { [weak self] _ in
        self?.paymentContext.pushPaymentMethodsViewController()
    }
}
```

Whenever I tap **paymentRow** nothing happens. It simply blinks, like a button with no action. Adding a viewController to the storyboard scene requires an identifier. That makes sense!

But there is no identifier in the code, so adding one logically raises an exception at run time. Not adding a viewController to the storyboard scene means there is no viewController pushed on the stack. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

How did you set up your paymentContext besides simply instantiating it?  Here is a bit of my own code for reference:

```
//custom class conforms to
STPPaymentContextDelegate

//class variable
var paymentContext: STPPaymentContext!

//in some function
let paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(apiAdapter: StripeAPIClient.sharedClient, configuration: config, theme: theme)
let userInformation = STPUserInformation()
paymentContext.prefilledInformation = userInformation

paymentContext.paymentAmount = 100
paymentContext.paymentCurrency = "usd"

self.paymentContext = paymentContext
self.paymentContext.delegate = self
paymentContext.hostViewController = self
```

**EDIT:**

Do you have:

```
paymentRow.configure(title: "Payment", detail: "Select Payment", theme: theme)
```

The configure method is what adds the action to the row view:

```
func configure(title: String, detail: String, tappable: Bool = true, theme: STPTheme) {

    self.title = title
    self.detail = detail

    self.backgroundColor = theme.secondaryBackgroundColor
    self.backgroundView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTap), for: .touchUpInside)
    if !tappable {
        self.backgroundView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        self.backgroundColor = theme.primaryBackgroundColor
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

**From the docs:**

```
open func pushPaymentMethodsViewController()
```

> This creates, configures, and appropriately pushes an `STPPaymentMethodsViewController` onto the navigation stack of the context's `hostViewController`. It'll be popped automatically when the user is done selecting their payment method.

**Custom Payment Row:**

Ignore that random segue, it goes to an unrelated controller.

[image]
[image]

Comment: that's it. Except my **BackendAPIAdapter** is **MyAPIClient** instead of **StripeAPIClient** but that's a detail. Everything else is identical.

Comment: Still nothing. Ugh.

Comment: Hey Frankie. Did not work. Also, the view controller is obviously not built into the method. I am using storyboards. I cannot add a storyboard to the scene without adding an identifier that allows me to segue.

Comment: Also, I essentially have the same code except I have **convenience init** in place of **func configure**, which again does not help with activating  paymentRow or pushing a new view onto the stack.

Comment: I have storyboards for my project but I don't use a storyboard for the payments method controller, thus there's no segue needed.  I posted the docs definition.  `pushPaymentMethodsViewController()` creates and pushes the new controller.  It was simple for me to setup, which means maybe there is something else going on in your project preventing this from happening.  Sorry!

Comment: Cool. That's what I thought. I was uncertain if pushPaymentMethodsViewController() created a new controller without my needing to add a new controller onto the scene. I thought as much, based on the docs. Now I just need to figure out why my paymentRow just blinks and doesn't call it. Thanks, man!

Comment: q: assuming you have a BrowseViewController storyboard and a CheckoutViewController storyboard on the scene, are you click/dragging from the BrowseViewController "Cell" to the CheckoutViewController scene, or from the BrowseViewController (yellow icon atop the storyboard) itself?

Comment: I am click/dragging from the Cell using the accessory view segue, which does not require an identifier. Just grasping at straws, here.

Comment: I don't have a browse controller because there is only one item to purchase.  I do have a custom view on my checkout controller, because I wanted to position it precisely, and had to create an outlet.  I will post a screen shot.

Comment: Thanks, man. Yeah, this should work, too, but... nothing: in **viewDidLoad** `self.paymentRow.onTap = {
            self.choosePaymentButtonTapped()
        }` Then as a standalone function `func choosePaymentButtonTapped() {
        paymentContext.pushPaymentMethodsViewController()
    }`

Comment: In your checkout view controller, what code specifically are you using to push the payment methods view controller, and where? Are you calling it in viewDidLoad? And are you using this weird syntax from Stripe's example: `var onTap: () -> () = {}`?

Comment: Haha, yeah I'm using the `onTap` definition they provided.  `configure` adds the selector for `didTap`, which in turn calls `onTap`.  `paymentRow.onTap = ...` is defined in `viewDidLoad`.  I'm not belaying it through another method (`choosePaymentButtonTapped`) like you are, but I don't think that should matter.

Comment: I initially had that implementation and was trying another [https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/standard]. I have since went back to the original from the docs, which is what I believe you have. Nothing! I know it's going to be something stupid and I'm missing it.

Comment: okay. So, I am able to push the view controller but it is just stuck loading. The payment row just spins and I can tap it to push the payment view controller on top. But it just loads. Any thoughts? Maybe it's a backend issue. Console says I have not provided an API key even though I have that explicitly atop the CheckoutViewController class.

Comment: Thanks again! Almost there!

Comment: No ideas, but for the api key make sure if you are using the dev key to have the dev key in your sever env, or likewise if you're in production.  I had my keys mismatched at one point and it caused lots of issues.

Comment: I have my secret key in my server env and my publishable key in my CheckoutViewController. It says success, but again no "Add a Card" view controller. I do get a status error of 401 about headers, though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I resolved it by using **.presentPaymentMethodsViewController()** instead of the **.pushPaymentMethodsViewController().** 
Same works for the **.pushShippingViewController()**, just rename it for **presentShippingViewController()**.

```swift
self.paymentRow.onTap = { [weak self] in
            self?.paymentContext.presentPaymentMethodsViewController()
        }
        self.shippingRow.onTap = { [weak self]  in
            self?.paymentContext.presentShippingViewController()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the code of `pushPaymentOptionsViewController`, `hostViewController` needs to be either `UINavigationController` or embedded inside a `UINavigationController`

```
- (void)pushPaymentOptionsViewController {
    NSCAssert(self.hostViewController != nil, @"hostViewController must not be nil on STPPaymentContext when calling pushPaymentOptionsViewController on it. Next time, set the hostViewController property first!");
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
    if ([self.hostViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.hostViewController;
    } else {
        navigationController = self.hostViewController.navigationController;
    }
    NSCAssert(self.hostViewController != nil, @"The payment context's hostViewController is not a navigation controller, or is not contained in one. Either make sure it is inside a navigation controller before calling pushPaymentOptionsViewController, or call presentPaymentOptionsViewController instead.");
    WEAK(self);
    [self.didAppearPromise voidOnSuccess:^{
        STRONG(self);
        if (self.state == STPPaymentContextStateNone) {
            self.state = STPPaymentContextStateShowingRequestedViewController;

            STPPaymentOptionsViewController *paymentOptionsViewController = [[STPPaymentOptionsViewController alloc] initWithPaymentContext:self];
            self.paymentOptionsViewController = paymentOptionsViewController;
            paymentOptionsViewController.prefilledInformation = self.prefilledInformation;
            paymentOptionsViewController.paymentOptionsViewControllerFooterView = self.paymentOptionsViewControllerFooterView;
            paymentOptionsViewController.addCardViewControllerFooterView = self.addCardViewControllerFooterView;
            if (@available(iOS 11, *)) {
                paymentOptionsViewController.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = self.largeTitleDisplayMode;
            }

            [navigationController pushViewController:paymentOptionsViewController
                                            animated:[self transitionAnimationsEnabled]];
        }
    }];
}
```