# 'hostViewController must not be nil on STPPaymentContext when calling pushPaymentOptionsViewController on it

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

This is my SignUpViewController:-

```
 import UIKit
 import Firebase
  import Stripe

   class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {
    var paymentContext = STPPaymentContext()
   @IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var passwordConfirm: UITextField!
   @IBAction func signUpAction(_ sender: Any) {
      if password.text != passwordConfirm.text {let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Password Incorrect", message: "Please re-type password", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
           
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
   self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else{
   Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!){ (user, error) in if error == nil {
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signupToHome", sender: self)
    
                }
     else{
   let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message:    error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
   let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                   
       alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
       self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
           }
             }
         }
    }

     @IBAction func userIconClicked(_ sender: Any){
   
  
    
       let userSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle:    .actionSheet)
    
    let logout = UIAlertAction(title: "Logout", style: .default) { (action) in
        // Logout
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
        } catch {
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    let manageCards = UIAlertAction(title: "Manage Credit Cards", style: .default) {  (action) in
        // Display Stripe Widget
        self.paymentContext.pushPaymentOptionsViewController()
    }
    
    let manageBanks = UIAlertAction(title: "Manage Bank Accounts", style: .default) { (action) in
        // Manage Bank Accounts
    }
    
    let close = UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .cancel)
    
    userSheet.addAction(manageCards)
    userSheet.addAction(manageBanks)
    userSheet.addAction(logout)
    userSheet.addAction(close)
    
    present(userSheet, animated: true)
 }
func setupStripe() {
    
    Wallet.instance.customerContext = STPCustomerContext(keyProvider:  StripeApiClient())
    
    let config = STPPaymentConfiguration.shared
    paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(customerContext:     Wallet.instance.customerContext,
                                       configuration: config(),
                                       theme: .default())
    
    paymentContext.hostViewController = self
    
     }
   }
```

This what it is in the simulator:--

[image]

The "Button" on the right-hand-upper-corner is linked to "@IBAction func userIconClicked(_ sender: Any)". When I click on this button, the following shows up on the simulator: -

[image]

Now, when I click on "Manage Credit Cards", it  shows error in the AppDelegate - -  Thread 1: "hostViewController must not be nil on STPPaymentContext when calling pushPaymentOptionsViewController on it. Next time, set the hostViewController property first! as shown in the screenshot below:-
[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Edit 1: after humnoz  comment, I called "setupStripe()", still same error -

```
  import UIKit
  import Firebase
  import Stripe

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {
var paymentContext = STPPaymentContext()
@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordConfirm: UITextField!
@IBAction func signUpAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if password.text != passwordConfirm.text {let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Password Incorrect", message: "Please re-type password", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
           
alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else{
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!){ (user, error) in if error == nil {
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signupToHome", sender: self)
    
                }
 else{
   let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
   let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                   
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
       }
            }
      }
}
func viewDidLoad(_ animated: Bool) {
    Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
        // If there is a user logged in, stay here on homeVC
        // else, take them to the login page.
        
        if user == nil {
            let loginVC = LoginRegisterVC()
            loginVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            self.present(loginVC, animated: true)
        } else {
            UserManager.instance.getCurrentUser {
                self.setupStripe()
            }
        }
    }
}
@IBAction func userIconClicked(_ sender: Any){
   
  
    
    let userSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    
    let logout = UIAlertAction(title: "Logout", style: .default) { (action) in
        // Logout
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
        } catch {
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    let manageCards = UIAlertAction(title: "Manage Credit Cards", style: .default) { (action) in
        // Display Stripe Widget
        self.paymentContext.pushPaymentOptionsViewController()
    }
    
    let manageBanks = UIAlertAction(title: "Manage Bank Accounts", style: .default) { (action) in
        // Manage Bank Accounts
    }
    
    let close = UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .cancel)
    
    userSheet.addAction(manageCards)
    userSheet.addAction(manageBanks)
    userSheet.addAction(logout)
    userSheet.addAction(close)
    
    present(userSheet, animated: true)
}
func setupStripe() {
    
    Wallet.instance.customerContext = STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: StripeApiClient())
    
    let config = STPPaymentConfiguration.shared
    paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(customerContext: Wallet.instance.customerContext,
                                       configuration: config(),
                                       theme: .default())
    
    paymentContext.hostViewController = self
    
  }

}
```

Comment: see this for help:[Stripe Checkout iOS integration with Storyboards in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711655/stripe-checkout-ios-integration-with-storyboards-in-swift-3)

Comment: are you calling `setupStripe()` in your code? I cannot see that you are. If you are not calling it, then the `hostViewController` property is not being set so the error message you see is accurate.

Comment: @humnoz - I called up stripe, still same error

Answer (score 0):

This post helped me im my case   - https://it.wenda123.org/question/stack/40711655/stripe-checkout-ios-integration-with-storyboards-in-swift-3